# How to create/display a static voxel_grid map?

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap-2d, voxel-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've searched quite a bit, and to no avail, for a modern, minimal example of creating a static voxel map and displaying that map in rviz. Most tutorials have incomplete steps, or aim at map creation within the whole navigation environment. Without sensors or navigation infrastructure, I wish to load a pre-existing global voxel map and display that in rviz. Is 3D map creation and publication possible without providing sensor sources? I was able to do this through `map_server` in 2D by providing a BMP file.

[This video](https://youtu.be/DM8swKliU4s) is a nice example of what I'd like to display, but they're clearly using sensor input.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278943/how-to-create/display-a-static-voxel_grid-map?/) by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 753 on 2018-01-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-05**:
What tutorials are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could do this using [octomap](http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_server), it's designed to update the map with point clouds from sensors but you could add a single point cloud containing your map at the start then keep this initial map for the duration of your experiment.

What format have you got the 3D map in that you want to display in rviz?

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0